# Using slick carousel with wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

i am getting this error on the web console  from the slick carousel plugin after I upload my WordPress theme to the internet

```
slick.min.js?ver=1:1 
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null
      at Object.e.initADA (slick.min.js?ver=1:1)
      at Object.e.init (slick.min.js?ver=1:1)
      at new <anonymous> (slick.min.js?ver=1:1)
      at a.fn.init.i.fn.slick (slick.min.js?ver=1:1)
      at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):275)
      at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
      at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
      at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
      at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

Everything works fine locally. I get the error only on the live WordPress website. I can see that it is something to do with Jquery and the slick.min.js. I really get confused because it works on the local development but not on the live website

This is the initializing code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function($){


      $('.slide_image').slick({
          autoplay: true,
          arrows: true,
          autoplaySpeed:5000,
      });
......
```

Comment: Why document ready two times, is this only error you are getting? can you check page source if you are loading jquery two times? try to replace document ready with jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //your code });

Comment: I have removed the second line of  `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` but nothing changed. Yes, it is the only error I am having and it occurs only on the live website. The development version has no issues

Comment: I think for WordPress `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` is correct format, remove `$(document).ready(function($)`